# Splitting string results in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, indefinite

I need to split this string and loop through the resulting array. However, even though my result string array has only 3 items, my loop goes to infinity.

I am probably missing something, but I can not see it at this point.

Here is the code:

```
CustomizeDashboardService.getCustomizedDashboard().then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);


            var sensors = res.sensor.split(',');
            var devices = res.uuid.split(',');;

            console.log("CS: S",sensors)   // I Can see these 2 arrays have only 3 items each,
            console.log("CS: D",devices)   //  but when it goes into my for loop, it iterates to indefinite

            for(i=0;i<devices.length-1;i++){
                console.log("girdi")  // I see this is logging more than 1000 times

                var index = findIndex(devices[i]);

                var obj = {
                    device:self.deviceList[index],
                    sensor: sensors[i]
                }

                self.customizedSensors.push(obj);


            }



            console.log("customized sensors",self.customizedSensors);


        })
```

Comment: What does `devices.length-1` give you?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<devices.length-1;i++)` has to be `for(var i=0;i<devices.length;i++)` to iterate over the complete array, or do you want to iterate only the first 2 elements if 3 are available?

Comment: My hunch is that since you are using `for(i=0;...)` rather than `for(var i = 0;...)` the `i` is a global and is being reset somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Yes I only need first 2, that s why I did length-1

Comment: @MustafaBereket ok, than you only missed the `var i = 0;` in this part of code

Comment: Worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop has `for(i=0;i<devices.length-1;i++)` which means the iteration variable is not locally scoped.  If somewhere else the `i` value is changed then it can cause issues.  As a matter of habit, always `var` your iterator variable unless you have a very specific reason not to (such situations do exist but are fairly rare).  To avoid other issues I would recommend looking through all of your code and making sure you have the `var` in there.